# Users getting blank screen on long uploads (which fail). Would that be max_execution_time or max_input_time?

Tags: php

I need to change a setting in php.ini to give our script more time to work with the upload.

Would that be max_execution_time? Or max_input_time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking for max_execution_time. No need to change it in php.ini though if you don't want to. I use this line on a few scripts:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "3000");
```

Comment: Note that "max_execution_time" starts counting *after* the upload to the webserver has finished and php is invoked for parsing the file. Means upload time doesn't count against max_execution_time. See the [post of @Pekka for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4220463/620410)

Answer (score 3):

Also, in case you are still having problems, ensure you have upload_max_filesize and post_max_size set at sufficient levels.