# Why does my script runs longer than my server set max_execution_time?

Tags: php, timeout, execution-time, timeoutexception

I have a script:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 7200; $i++) {
    echo $i.' - ';
    sleep(1);
}
```

But my server has:

```
ini_get('max_execution_time'); // == 30
```

Why script runs 7200 seconds (not execution time out), but max_execution_time is 30?
set_time_limit () on the server is turned off

Comment: The `set_time_limit()` function and the configuration directive `max_execution_time` only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using `system()`, the `sleep()` function, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time you spend in `sleep` doesn't count towards the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` time is not taking in account as it is a system call.

See [How does PHP max_execution_time work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220413/how-does-php-max-execution-time-work?rq=1)

Comment: +1 for explanation about why it is not taken into account and providing link...I can't guess why you have got less upvotes then other here when you have given first answer

Answer (score 0):

sleep is not affected by max_execution_time

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Answer (score 0):

`max_execution_time` only affects script time not system calls like `sleep()`.

```
sleep ($seconds);
```

sleep — Delay execution